# Oracle Number data type and its strictness

Tags: oracle

I'm very new to oracle but I've been learning about it in class and I've recently come across the `number` data type. I've read the documentation regarding scale and precision (s,p) but I still am not positive regarding the type's proper usage.

Let's say I want to store percent values as a decimal. The decimal can be anywhere from 0 to 1 and may have up to 3 numbers following the decimal place.

Some possible decimals to be stored may include:

```
.66
.553
1.00
```

If I were to make the column `NUMBER(4,3)` would that work EVEN IF there were only two numbers? See below

```
.22
.10
.35
etc...
```

In short, does the number type require that the EXACT sizes are met? Eg. Would NUMBER(4,3) ABSOLUTELY REQUIRE that the data inserted is 4 numbers, 3 of them falling after the decimal place?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A `number(4, 3)` could hold values from -9.999 to 9.999, inclusive. To keep the numbers within the valid range you want, in addition to declaring it of type `number(4,3)` a check constraint would be called for. `create table t (n number(4,3) constraint t_c0 check (t between 0 and 1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data types for columns limit the range of values that can be stored.  But they don't do anything to force a particular length or precision.

Just like you can store a single character or a NULL in a `VARCHAR2(100)` column, you can store numbers with less than 3 digits of precision and less than 4 digits of scale.  For example, the values 0 and 6.1 are both perfectly valid for a `NUMBER(4,3)` column.  If you insert a value that has too many digits of precision, the value will be silently rounded to the precision specified in the column definition.

```
SQL> create table foo (
  2    col1 number(4,3)
  3  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 9.999 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values (0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 6.1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 1.2345 );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1
----------
     9.999
         0
       6.1
     1.235
```

Comment: Thank you, the VARCHAR comparison made perfect sense to me.

Comment: Don't have time to test, but I believe that Oracle will round or truncate when assigning a value with larger precision. For example you could store 0.225232 in a `number(4, 3)` column.

Comment: I know for a fact that the above statement is incorrect. When I tested that, I was given errors saying that the number was too precise for the column (not in those words though).

Comment: @Evan - Actually, Shannon is correct, you can attempt to insert a value with more precision into the column and it will be silently rounded to the precision specified in the column definition.  Updated my answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: I'll post the test I did yesterday - won't be able to do so until tonight though.